# Odd icon in Sublime Text 3

Tags: django, sublimetext3

I'm working in Django in ST3. This doesn't used to happen but now whenever I create a new app using `./manage.py startapp userx` I get a weird icon in ST3 that I can't open. Has anyone seen this before?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon is an indication that the folder in question is a `link`; or more specifically that Sublime thinks that the folder is identical to another folder that it's already seen in the project.

This determination is made via use of low level file system meta information, such as `inode` information on Linux, etc. It has been known to go wrong in the past for some network file systems that provide inaccurate meta information. Additionally, there is currently no way to disable this behaviour in Sublime should this occur.

Folders that are marked as links are marked while Sublime is crawling the project folders to discover the contents for use in the side bar, for indexing, and so on. The reason for the detection is to stop a runaway index in cases where a folder might be a link to somewhere above itself in the hierarchy, which would result in an infinite number of files being found.

If you right click on a folder that's a link, the context menu will show a `Reveal Link Source` command that will show you what folder Sublime thinks that folder is linked to.

Comment: I deleted a symlink I created in that folder and suddenly the folders were working fine. That might have been the problem.